# Mysqldump replaces foreign characters with � for utf8mb4 database

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I've looked around Google and read some other topics in SO but nothing proposed has worked for me so far.

Here is the setup of my database in question:

```
character_set_client        utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database      utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results       utf8mb4
character_set_server        latin2
character_set_system        utf8 
ft_query_extra_word_chars   OFF
```

I have a tiny `db_dump.sh` file that contains this line:

```sh
TABLELIST_WITH_DATA="
lc_users
lc_history
lc_feedback
"

HOST=sql.myserver.com

PRO=lc_current
DEV=lc_development
STG=lc_staging

ENV=$1
ENV_L=$(echo "$1" | awk '{print tolower($0)}')

FILENAME_DATA=data_$ENV_L.sql

mysqldump -h ${HOST} -u ${!ENV} -p --default-character-set=latin1 --no-create-info --skip-triggers --hex-blob --skip-set-charset ${!ENV} ${TABLELIST_WITH_DATA} > $FILENAME_DATA
```

I tried setting different character sets

```sh
--default-character-set=ut8
--default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

or removing `--skip-set-charset`

All my attempts still produce strings with � instead of proper accented characters or letters from different alphabets. Nothing seems to work, hence any ideas are welcome!

When trying to open this file in MySQL Workbench I'm getting this error:

[image]

Selecting `latin1` opens the file but with chars like `³êñ¼¶`

Selecting `utf8mb4` shows another error:
[image]

And lastly, the error if I select UTF-8:
[image]

Comment: If you're getting the placeholder character, it could mean that the data is incorrectly stored in your database. Try to find a table cell that produces this, see what the table/column charset is set as and what actual bytes are stored.

Comment: What program do you use when viewing the dump? Maybe the � is just shown in whatever editor/viewer you use? Have you checked it with a hex editor to be really something wrong?

Comment: I used Notepad, VSCode, and MySQL Workbench. Surprisngly MySQL Workbench showed a warning I included in my original question

Comment: What text were you expecting to see?

Comment: `ąółśńźżę` Polish letters with diacritic marks